# Place a IconSet conditional formatting rule last within a squence of rules VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a VBA procedure that places a number of conditional formatting rules on a worksheet. One of the rules is for an icon set, the icon set always ends up as the first rule, I need it to be the last rule or a least under a rule that hides one of the icons in the set so it is blank under its condition, by using the "Stop If True" option in the rule above it. Is this normal behavior for the icon set rule to put itself first regardless where it is in the VBA code?

I think an alternate approach would be to make the icon blank, like the "No Cell Icon" option that you can do manually, in a cell if it meets its criteria, but I don't know if there is an option for the criteria property. Something similar to the .ShowIconOnly = True for the FormatConitions(1).

```
      With .FormatConditions(1)
     .SetFirstPriority
     .ReverseOrder = False
     .ShowIconOnly = False
     .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl5Arrows)       
   .
   .
  With .IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 2
        .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
   End With
```

The rule that I want before the Iconset rule is this.

```
     With Range("N3:N200").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=$D3=""CV Sent""")

    .Interior.color = RGB(198, 239, 206) 'Light green
   ' .Interior.color = xlNone
    .Font.color = RGB(0, 97, 0) 'A dark color
    '.Font.color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White
    .StopIfTrue = True
   End With
```

Comment: Creating FormatConditions always puts the newly created CFR at the end of the queue unless you reorder them or use SetFirstPriority. I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: I am trying to get the condition $D3="CV Sent" to be above the Iconset condition, no matter where I put the iconset conditon in the procedure it is always the first condition in the conditional formatting dialog. I am cycling through 20 worksheets so don't want to move it manually. Is there an option not to show a specific criteria icon in a cell?

Comment: I removed the SetFirstPriorit and it made no difference in the order.